# Summarize single row values on a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with some weather data, structured in this way:

```
DATA                TEMP    UM  RAIN
2017-05-16 10:00    13.2    80  0.0
2017-05-16 10:05    13.1    81  0.1
....
2017-05-16 23:55    2.1     90  0.5
2017-05-17 00:00    2.1     91  0.0
2017-05-17 00:05    2.1     91  0.5
```

For every step interval (5 minutes) I have some data. The value of rain is the total cumulated in these steps. 
What I need is a new column with the daily progressive value from 00:00 to 23:55. On the last daily data (23:55) I must have the total rain fall in the day, and at the 00:00 the counter has to start again from 0.0. For example:

```
DATA                TEMP    UM  RAIN
2017-05-16 10:00    13.2    80  2.1
2017-05-16 10:05    13.1    81  2.2
....
2017-05-16 23:55    2.1     90  12.2
2017-05-17 00:00    2.1     91  0.0
2017-05-17 00:05    2.1     91  0.5
```

I need the best solution to do this, in PHP or directly in MySQL. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single SQL query using variables:

```sql
SELECT DATA, TEMP, UM,
       @r := IF(TIME(DATA) = '00:00:00', RAIN, RAIN + @r)
FROM mytable 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0.0) AS v
ORDER BY DATA;
```

The query uses [**TIME**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) in order to extract the time portion out of the datetime field.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/HCBIG1833)

Comment: +1 though I'd wouldn't use imprecise float for the data type in this case.  Decimal(6,3) would be more than enough most likely;  but quick/dirty example I suppose. 999 inches of rain is what 83 feet?  if anyplace gets that much in 1 day... they're sunk! :P

Comment: @xQbert Yes, this was just a quick & dirty way to set up an example. `Decimal(6,3)` seems like a very reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos. It's possible to have the final query to insert the result on a new column (ex. rain_total)?

Comment: @Andrea75 Yes, this is trivial. Just select `RAIN` field and alias the result returned by `@r`, like  `SELECT DATA, TEMP, UM, RAIN, @r := IF(...) AS rain_total`.

Comment: Thanks again @Giorgos Betsos! ;)

Comment: Sorry @GiorgosBetsos, maybe I'm a disaster... the query works fine, but if I try to populate the new coloum running this query:

INSERT INTO `TABLE 1` (rain_total)
SELECT DATA, TEMP, UM,
       @r := IF(TIME(DATA) = '00:00:00', RAIN, RAIN + @r)
FROM mytable 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0.0) AS rain_total
ORDER BY DATA;

I obtain this error:
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @Andrea75 The `INSERT` declares only one field, whereas `SELECT` uses 4. You have to rewrite `INSERT` like: `INSERT INTO  yourTable (DATA, TEMP, UM, RAIN_TOTAL) SELECT DATA, TEMP, UM, @r := IF(TIME(DATA) = '00:00:00', RAIN, RAIN + @r) FROM ...`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, all goes fine for all day that start with 00:00, but when the first date time is different (ex. 00:05 or 00:13) the counter doesn't reset... :(

Comment: @Andrea75 In your question you state that *For every step interval (5 minutes) I have some data* ... I tried to write a query that uses this assumption. If you have a different requirement then try posting a new question.

Comment: Yes @GiorgosBetsos, because the DB contains about a milion of records (12 years) so I had not able to check all data... only now I saw that are not all equals.. :(
Anyway this my new question where I think I'm explain better my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018861/sum-daily-data-on-mysql-and-reset-counter-when-data-change
Thanks in advance if you could help me again. :)