# Sum daily data on MySQL and reset counter when data change

Tags: mysql

I have a MySLQ DB with weather data structured in this way:

```
DATA                TEMP    UM  RAIN
2017-05-16 10:00    13.2    80  0.0
2017-05-16 10:05    13.1    81  0.1
....
2017-05-16 23:55    2.1     90  0.5
2017-05-17 00:00    2.1     91  0.0
2017-05-17 00:05    2.1     91  0.5
```

I need to populate another column with progressive daily cumulated rain, as this:

```
DATA                TEMP    UM  RAIN    TOT_RAIN
2017-05-16 10:00    13.2    80  0.0     2.2 
2017-05-16 10:05    13.1    81  0.1     2.3
....
2017-05-16 23:55    2.1     90  0.5     12.3
2017-05-17 00:00    2.1     91  0.0     0.0
2017-05-17 00:05    2.1     91  0.5     0.5
```

I tried with this query, that works:

```
UPDATE `alldata` t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT DateTime,@r := IF(TIME(DateTime) >= '00:00:00' AND < '00:05:00', R_OLD, R_OLD + @r) R
    FROM `alldata`
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0.0) AS R
    ORDER BY DateTime
) t2 ON t1.DateTime = t2.DateTime
SET t1.R = t2.R
```

But when timedate of the new day is not equal to 00:00 (this could be 00:01, as 01:05 or 03:00) the query fail, and the counter doesn't reset to zero.
I need that the last data of the day contain the total of daily rain, and the first on new day equal to zero.
Any help?

Comment: I'd not write this to the table data but create a view with the aggregate.

Comment: I need this kind of data format because is required by a web template that I have to use... :(

Comment: Sure, but do you really need it to be a table? It should be transparent for your web template if it queries the table or a view (unless you cannot change the query to point to a view at all).

Comment: Yes... I cannot change the query... I need to replicate the exactely DB structure, even if my data are in a different way.

Comment: A view can replicate the underlying table structure - plus the calculated column you need. It would merely be replacing `SELECT * FROM alldata ...` by `SELECT * FROM v_alldata ...` in your template.

Comment: At the moment the easiest way (form me) is to modify the table, maybe using PHP too....

Comment: It doesn't sound easy from your question. Anyway this is all the help I can offer. Good luck.